# Find unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^*AU$ is diagonal, where $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ i & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ i & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Find a unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{*} A U = D$ where $D$ is diagonal.

Now the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ with eigenvector $(i,1)$ and $2$ with eigenvector $(-i,1)$ and they are not orthogonal to one another. So we need to apply gram-schmidt process to orthogonalize this basis.
But once I started, the norm of the vectors is $0$ so I can not normalize them! What do I do in such a case?

Comment: Surely those eigenvectors ARE orthogonal with respect to the usual Hermitian inner product (which I assume you are using).

Comment: Applying the Gram-Schmidt process to eigenvectors for different eigenvalues is always a bad idea: though this may give you an orthonormal basis, it won't consist of eigenvectors (you might as well just take the standard basis instead, which is also orthonormal). Here the fact that $A$ is Hermitian (easy to check) _ensures_ you that it has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors, and since all eigenvalues are distinct, _every_ basis of eigenvectors (including the one you found) will be orthogonal. You just need to normalise. Leave Gram-Schmidt for the rare case of an eigenvalue with multiplicity.

Comment: The eigenvectors *are* orthogonal: if you correctly do $u^Hv$, you find $(-i)(-i)+1\cdot1=-1+1=0$.

Comment: Marc, thanks, I did not know that if $A$ is Hermitian then the eigenvectors are of an orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The norm of the vectors can't be zero as they both are non-zero vectors. Assuming you're working with the usual euclidean inner (scalar) product, we have:

$$||(i,1)||^2=\langle (i,1)\,,\,(i,1)\rangle=i\cdot\overline i+1\cdot\overline 1=i(-i)+1\cdot 1=2\\||(-i,1)||^2=\langle (-i,1)\,,\,(-i,1)\rangle=(-i)\cdot\overline{(-i)}+1\cdot\overline 1=(-i)(i)+1\cdot 1=2$$

so both vectors' norm is $\;\sqrt2\;$ ...